# springSecurity.denied.message in grails 2.2.2

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

i am trying to Different home page for user depending upon its Role

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = "/home"

 grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType="InterceptUrlMap"
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap=[
....
....
'/User/**':['ROLE_USER'],
'/home/**':['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER'],
....
....
]
```

i set success handler controller "HomeController"

in that i redirect role wise home page

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

class HomeController {
   def index() {

      if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
         redirect controller: '...', action: '...'
         return
      }
      if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
         redirect controller: 'user', action: 'show'
         return
      }

   }
```

}

In this When i logged in through ADMIN Profile it hits "HomeController" and redirect as well

But When I trying to Log In from User Profile it gives me an error **springSecurity.denied.message...**

Comment: Make sure your user have the ROLE_USER and have access to the redirected action. If you comment the interceptUrlMap and it works, it's probably a role problem.

Comment: But in my code its hits the Home controller when i logged in through admin...

Comment: i updated my question please check it

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your redirect call:

```
redirect controller: 'UserController'
```

it should be

```
redirect controller: 'user'
```

Because in this cases you follow the url convension: `:8080/your-app/user/show`

Comment: i written user ... but still its gives an same error.. but still its not hitting to home controller..

Comment: Your user have the ROLE_USER?

Comment: Yup... my user have a role ROLE_USER

Answer (score 0):

```
'/user/**':['ROLE_USER'],
```

instead

```
'/User/**':['ROLE_USER'],
```